# tinyMCE's iframe or table height is not resizing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

I have successfully added a tinyMCE editor to my web-app so that users can make notes. I have the textarea it replaces inside a div, so that the div can resize with the page, and the textarea can always be set at width: 100% and height: 100%

My tinyMCE.init looks as follows:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "specific_textareas",
  editor_selector: "notes-editor",
  theme: "advanced",
  plugins: "",
  theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,forecolor,backcolor",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
  theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "none",
  theme_advanced_resizing: false,
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%"
});
```

Unfortunately, this returns an editor that looks as follows:
[image]

No matter how I change the height, be it from CSS or JS, that "strip" of where I can edit never changes. The odd thing is that this only applies to the height.

I have done everything from trying to change the table (i.e. `note_contents_tbl`) to the iframe (i.e. `note_contents_ifr`) but nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the height and width to 100% doesn't work. TinyMCE creates the editor inside an iframe, which in turn is nested inside a table. Setting height to 100% does not inherit the size of the div.

I think this could be your problem and if really this is the problem then you should change the `width` and `height` values from `%` to numeric values exactly the `width` and `height` of your wrapper div or whatever you want and to do so remove the `%` from `init` just use, i.e.

```
height: "300",
width: "500"
```

To change the size programmatically you can use

```
var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
var width = '500';
var height = '300';
ed.theme.resizeTo(width, height);
```

[**tinyMCE Configuration**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) and another answer on [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143581/how-to-set-the-width-of-textarea-using-tinymce).

Comment: Thank you Sheikh. That's exactly the line of code I needed (the `ed.theme.resize`). I had seen the setting the width to non-% worked, but I couldn't resize it. Would you know how to select a specific editor, in the even I have 2 on a page and I want to resize only one? E.g. is there a `var ed = tinymce.activeEditor(selector)`?

Comment: Welcome and yes there is `<textarea id="myarea1"></textarea> var ed=tinyMCE.get('myarea1')` :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS makes TinyMCE handle `height: 100%` as the remaining space:

```
td.mceIframeContainer, td.mceIframeContainer iframe { position: fixed; }
```