# Resize Tiny MCE

Tags: php, javascript, css, tinymce

I'm creating a custom content management system with a rich text editor. I'm using tiny MCE but I'm failing to fit the text area in my content div. I have a `<div></div>`  that is 680px. I want Tiny MCE to fit into the `<div></div>` properly. However it keeps on overflowing. How can I set the textarea to fit on a width of 680px? Thaks. A sample of my code is down below

```
<?php
require 'janta_class.php';
$jantaObj = new janta_class();
if (!isset($_GET['pgid']) || empty($_GET['pgid'])) {
    $page_id = 1;
} else {
    $page_id = $_GET['pgid'];
}
if (isset($page_id) && !empty($page_id)) {
    $allowedTags = '<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img>';
    $allowedTags.='<li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del>';

    //you might want to escape some literals here
    $page_data = $jantaObj->get_page($page_id);
    $page_content = $page_data['page_content'];
    $page_title = $page_data['page_title'];

    $page_content = strip_tags(stripslashes($page_content), $allowedTags);
}
?>

<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./editor/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode: "exact",
        elements : "rteditor",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,visualblocks",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,visualblocks",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        },  
        height:"350px",
        width:"600px"
    });

</script>

<?php //echo $sHeader;   ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea id="rteditor" name="rteditor" rows="15" cols="80"><?php echo $page_content; ?></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: similar question at SO with solution [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143581/how-to-set-the-width-of-textarea-using-tinymce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use width with double quotes nor single quotes.

I have got the solution.

Put it like:

```
width: 300,
```

and it should work for you. I have tested it with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to set the width in the tinymce initfunction. Be aware that you place integers there and don't use 'px':

```
    width:"680"
```

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this or otherwise provide a page with an example??