# How to set width from tinyMCE in Wicket

Tags: wicket, tinymce-3

Cant set any width from tinyMCE3 in Wicket. I already used google :D
but with no result. How can i control the size from tinyMCE?

```java
final TextArea<String> textTextField = new TextArea<String>("text");
textTextField.setLabel(new StringResourceModel("text.module.edit.text", TextModuleEditPanel.this));
textTextField.setRequired(true);

final TinyMCESettings settings = new 
TinyMCESettings(TinyMCESettings.Theme.advanced);
// Some other settings

settings.addCustomSetting("cleanup : false");
settings.addCustomSetting("verify_html : false");
settings.addCustomSetting("plugins: 'autoresize'");
settings.setResizing(Boolean.TRUE);

TinyMceBehavior tinyMceBehavior = new TinyMceBehavior(settings);

textTextField.add(tinyMceBehavior);

form.add(textTextField);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
settings.addCustomSetting("width : '500'");
settings.addCustomSetting("height : '300'");
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4145058/497381 this is how TinyMCE 3 should be initialized.